# How to insert a table with a \raggedleft text and how to fix the hole table in the left

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am a new with `Latex` and I would like to correct this `table`:

1. I need the texts to be on left
2. I need to shift the hole table
   in the left also so it will be clearer

[image]

Comment: Hello! Could you share the tex source code which generated this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To align the whole object (table) to left, use `\begin{flushleft} ...    \end{flushleft}`.

To align the text in cells in a column to left, center or right, use 'l', 'c' or 'r' in the description of your `tabular`, like bellow.

```
 \begin{flushleft}
  \begin{table}
   \begin{tabular}{lcrrr}
    \hline
    Minta   & pH & time & d     & eltáv.\\
    \hline
    e-Ni-NA1    & ? & 7100  & 18 & Marás     \\
    e-Ni-NA2    & ? & 7100  & 18 & Marás     \\
    e-Ni-NA3    & 3.3   & 7200  & 18 & Cellux    \\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
  \end{table} 
 \end{flushleft}
```

Comment: \begin{flushleft} ... \end{flushleft} is not working